# How to join multiple tables together in a query

Tags: mysql

I am fairly new to MySQL and am having a problem getting data to pull into a table from multiple tables (if that makes sense!) I can get the data out in rows, but not columns - where am I going wrong?

This is what I have so far: (restricted to 'id=18' for testing)

```
SELECT name from users where id=18
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as ACTIVE_RADARS FROM `radars` as at WHERE DATE(`lastHeartbeat`) = CURDATE() AND userId = 18 GROUP BY `userId`
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as ALERTS_TODAY FROM `alerts` as at WHERE DATE(`created_at`) = CURDATE() AND userId = 18 GROUP BY `userId`
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as ALERTS_THIS_MONTH  FROM `alerts` as atm WHERE `userId` = 18 AND created_at > DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') GROUP BY `userId`
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as SCANNED_TODAY FROM `scanned_urls` as at WHERE DATE(`created_at`) = CURDATE() AND userId = 18 GROUP BY `userId`
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as SCANNED_THIS_MONTH FROM `scanned_urls` as sim WHERE `userId` = 18 AND created_at > DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') GROUP BY `userId`
```

as it stands i get rows in one column, but I need 1 row in multiple columns.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use the JOIN keyword instead of UNION

Comment: Thanks for replying, my knowledge of Joins is pretty much non-existent, where would I need to insert `JOIN`

Comment: For a start you should read the MySQL reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the start:

```
SELECT u.name
  FROM users 
 WHERE u.id = 18
```

Then we can get count of rows

```
SELECT r.userid
     , COUNT(*) AS active_radars
  FROM `radars` r 
 WHERE r.lastheartbeat >= DATE(NOW()) 
   AND r.lastheartbeat <  DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
   AND r.userid = 18 
 GROUP
    BY r.userId
```

We can make that query an inline view, and perform an outer join. Something like this:

```
SELECT u.name
     , ar.active_radars
     , al.alerts_today
  FROM users

  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT r.userid
              , COUNT(*) AS active_radars
           FROM `radars` r 
          WHERE r.lastheartbeat >= DATE(NOW()) 
            AND r.lastheartbeat <  DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
            AND r.userid = 18 
          GROUP
             BY r.userId
       ) ar
    ON ar.userid = u.id

  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT a.userid
              , COUNT(*) AS alerts_today
           FROM `alerts` a
          WHERE a.created_at >= CURDATE()
            AND a.created_at <  CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
            AND a.userid = 18
          GROUP
             BY a.userid
       ) al
   ON al.userid = u.id

 WHERE u.id = 18
```

---

Given that we only need to return counts, as an alternative to join, we could be to use correlated subqueries in the SELECT list.